# What could cause Intel RST to not recognise a drive?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, intel-rst

I have a Windows 8 system that has four disks: (1) Samsung 840 Pro (system drive, C:), (2) 2TB SATA III Seagate (secondary drive, D:), (3) 2TB SATA II Western Digital (Backup Drive, Z:), and (4) a 64GB Crucial m4 mSATA (not yet partitioned). All drives are running on the same SATA controller, and I have RAID enabled in BIOS. The motherboard is a Gigabyte Z77-DS3H.

I want to use the m4 to accelerate the Seagate 2TB drive. I have Intel RST 12.5.0.1066 installed. When I click on the "Performance" tab and then click "Enable acceleration", the Crucial M4 is automatically selected as the solid-state drive I want to use. But below, where I am to "Select the disk or volume to accelerate", only one disk is listed - the backup 2TB drive (see image below). My D: drive is not listed. On previous versions of Intel RST, the drive would be listed, but when I tried to select it I would get an unknown error.

I have already tried switching the SATA cables around, in case there was a problem with that port, but that didn't fix the problem.

So, my questions is: What could be causing Intel RST to not recognise the drive?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I fixed this by running DISKPART and CLEANing the disk. So I guess that at least one answer to my own question is that a corrupt partition table can prevent caching.